# PHP download files from csv, timing out?

Tags: php, csv, file-get-contents

I have a php file below, which looks into the file "index.csv", which contains two headers, file|path

The file below downloads the requested xml files into the folder "productxml".

However, it seems to be timing out or something as it is only downloading 698 of the files, where there are over 300,000 files being referenced in the csv file above.

Any ideas on what might be the problem?

```
<?php
  set_time_limit(0);
$fileContent = file("index.csv"); // read the file to an array
array_shift($fileContent); // remove the first line, the header, from the array
foreach( $fileContent as $line ) {
    $columns = str_getcsv( $line, "|", '"' );
    $url = $columns[1]; // as suposed previously the url is in the second column
    $filename = $columns[0];
    downloadFile( $url, $filename );
}

function downloadFile( $url, $filename ) {
    $newfname = "../productxml/" . $filename ;
    $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
    if ($file) {
        $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");
        if ($newf)
            while(!feof($file)) {
                fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
            }
    }
    if ($file) {
        fclose($file);
    }

    if ($newf) {
        fclose($newf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the connection stable? What is you `max_execution_time` setting in your `php.ini` file?

Comment: @byf-ferdy Max_execution_time = 64400

Comment: so you're probably running out of time. You could use a cronjob to split the downloads

Answer (score 0):

You may be running out of memory. Try setting

```
<?php
ini_set("memory_limit","240M")//set your preferred count
```

Comment: Is there not a way to perhaps tell it to download in blocks of 500 at a time and the sleep for a second and the resume where it left off, thus refreshing memory etc? Thanks for your help